# Failed to bring up wlan0

Tags: ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu Server, and this is what my */etc/network/interfaces* looks like:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
     address 192.168.1.68
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     gateway 192.168.1.254
```

and it gives me this error when I try to do *sudo ifup wlan0*

```
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up wlan0
```

Comment: Has anybody solved this problem?? I am stuck for the last two days in this... :( please help...

Comment: try ip route show or something like this. read man ip for further informations.

Answer (score 5):

That message usually means that the route being added already exists.

1. Run `sudo ifdown wlan0` and `sudo ifconfig wlan0 down` (these will probably output errors, just continue).
2. Then check the output of `ip route` for any routes related to wlan0. If there are any use `sudo ip route del` to remove them (for example, `sudo ip route del 192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0`).
3. Try `sudo ifup wlan0` again.

Comment: `sudo ifdown wlan0` gave me the error: `interface wlan0 not configured`.

Comment: @IsaiahBugarin Yes, it will give errors. Now check the routes and then try bringing it up again.

Comment: That command gave me `192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.68`.  ifup gave me same error still.

Comment: @IsaiahBugarin Edited.

Comment: `sudo ifdown wlan0` output error, the other one did not.  `ip route` didn't output anything.  `sudo ifup wlan0` gave error.

Comment: Can you help me?

Answer (score -3):

Try setting `gateway 192.168.1.1`.
It is a default value of most Wifi routers. This helped me.