# RTNETLINK answers: File exists in alpine router

Tags: linux, networking, routing, router, alpine

I already know that this ask may already be made here but i couldnt solve this there, idk if i made bad or something, so im asking with my own case, sorry if my english is bad but here it is

this is how i have the content of /etc/network/interfaces

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQY3K.png)

for some reason, when i do ifup in eth1 it retrieves RTNETLINK answers: File exists but the strange thing is here:

it only happens in up ip route add 192.168.1.0 ... 192.168.100.101 ...

but if i comment the 192.168.1.0 line and uncomment the 192.168.2.0, 192.168.3.0 and any other line below...

this works, everything works, my virtual machines connect well with the router and with internet, but its not what i need cause i have all my virtual machines with 192.168.1.... ip`s, and cant change it now, so i need this route to be 192.168.1, and well, i have the said error message

and thatas all, thanks for reading, im still studyng so this can be a problem ogf how i configure anythin, but cant imagine what can be
if anyone has any idea of what can be or how to solve this, im glad of reading

Comment: Please add all information to the question as text instead of an image, it makes it much easier to read / quote.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dhclient: What does "RTNETLINK answers: File exists" Mean?](https://serverfault.com/questions/601450/dhclient-what-does-rtnetlink-answers-file-exists-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system has an `eth0` interface, where the subnet is `192.168.1.0/24`.

When you are trying to add a route on second interface for the same subnet, the kernel returns the error message, because that would create duplicate routing entry for the subnet: One via `eth0` interface and another via `192.168.100.101` router.

Comment: thanks! i didnt tought that the eth0 interface would cause a problem there

Comment: To avoid this issue you can use `ip route replace` instead `ip route add`.